# How to resize a Image coming from api in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to know about how can I resize my image which is coming from a api.Image being high resolution takes time to load. So I want to resize them during the load.

Comment: you can use image cache library like for eg this [link](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) or can try another.

Comment: How can we make that image zoomable?

Answer (score 1):

Greetins Eshant Bist

You can use native image loader such: SDWebImage in iOS and Glide in Android
Or you can search for react image loader.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the [image-resizer module](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer). It is fairly easy to use and is quite to reliable.